# Make an application to auto accept form

Tags: forms, web

My school's "open wireless" network makes users accept an agreement before they can log onto the web.  I use this network for my normal school work for everyday and it's annoying do do this before I can go anywhere else.

I want to make an app to auto accept this before I go online.  Preferably I would like to use Python or Java (because I could type up something in either of those languages very quickly).

Here is a screen shot of the screen I would like to bypass.[image]

Comment: If you could "type up something in either of those languages very quickly" then why don't you?

Comment: I am looking for people who can help me figure out what classes or functions to use because I don't know how to write a program that interfaces with the web.  Just because I know the language doesn't mean I can do anything with it.  Maybe if you weren't such an ass you could help instead of posting smart-ass comments.

Comment: I apologise, I didn't mean to sound aloof. But there is much documentation, for both languages, on how to interact with web services. Your question is very open-ended; there are many equally effective ways to reach the same conclusion in both languages, hence it's difficult to answer and probably won't attract too much attention. Questions are better received here if they are about a specific problems with specific pieces of code. Try writing something, and if you get stuck with a particular library or error message, ask a question. I hope this is a little more helpful :)